# Best practice for Chef, ec2, knife and reducing the time to boot and ami in the event of a failover

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I an in the process of placing all of my servers under the control of chef for scm using chef server.  It works great....I love it.  I think I am starting to get the zen but I stil need a better understanding.

Prior, on ec2 i built ami's and I was always rebuilding ami's but at least they boot fast.

With chef, i gather, is to always start with a barebones instance and use knife to build your ami.

It takes about 20 minutes to launch an ami of which installing chef is about 5-6 minutes.

Issue I have is that I am running 4 servers, two redis, master and slave and two nginx servers under load balancing.

On a remote machine I have python scripts that are always checking if a a redis master or slave is down and for the load balancer if the nginx servers if they are healthy.

Now, under chef, if a server goes down I have to wait an extra 15+ minutes where under pre-built ami's the length of time was the time to boot up a new instance.

Questions I have are the following:

1) Is there a python api to interact with knife?  In python I used boto to boot an ami.  Now, I will have to use a popen to execute knife.  My code depends on knowing when the ami is up and running to continue further processing.

2) Is it best practice to have an ami where chef client is pre installed? That would shave about 6 minites off.

3) finally, what else am I missing?  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) https://github.com/coderanger/pychef  That is a python client for the chef api.  Not knife per se, so it won't give you access to any plugins you might use, but it should let you interact with the chef server

2) I don't do this, because I like to use the stock ubuntu ami's, but it seems like this would be a completely reasonable approach.  There are probably already ami's available like this, but I don't know off hand.  **Edit:** I forgot, there is the chef-omnibus installer: http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/ which installs via a deb (IIRC)

3) I don't think you are missing anything profound, to be honest.  But, I definitely think that chef should be a tool that you use to make your life easier, faster and more consistent.  So, I would use it in the way that is most effective to you.  If having a pre-built ami works best, then that seems like the best solution.  Sorry, I don't have any more insight.